# can't resolve dns

Tags: dns, lamp

I've setup a LAMP server with Ubuntu. It's a dedicated server hosted by `online.net`.

Now, I've purchased a domain name and I've created a **A registar mapping** to my server's IP address `http://88.191.157.10/`.

If you browse to this IP address, this will reach my website *(the 404 is expected)*. However, if you browse to the website using the dns

```
http://samuel-*-***.fr
```

then you end up on a parking page of `online.net`...
I did a dig on the dns and it returns the correct IP address. So I'm not sure what I'm missing here...

**Note:** that if on my server I browse to the website using the domain name, then it works. So it must be something simple I've missed.

**Edit**: since it seems to come from my apache web config, here it is :

```
<VirtualHost 88.191.157.10:80>
ServerName samuel-***-*.fr
ServerAlias www.samuel-**-*.fr
ServerAdmin test@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/ePhotograph/web
DirectoryIndex app.php
<Directory "/var/www/ePhotograph/web">
 AllowOverride All
 Allow from All
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I get a 404. Are you sure it's not just your browser cache that fools you?

Comment: Sounds like you have a local DNS cache issue - works for me.

Comment: @Sam your server isn't aliasing www. starting with your full domain name. Is a misconfiguration, but if you don't tell us the server you are using, we wouldn't be able to help you.

Comment: the web server is apache2, (that's the A in LAMP :) )Is that what you meant ?

Comment: I've edited my post to provide with more details. As you can see I do use an alias for www (I thought that'd do the trick)

Comment: I end up on the same place (404) with and without www.

Comment: @l3dx, really ? Try this http://www.samuel-berthelot.fr/app.php/accueil with and without the www. You should definitely not see the same thing.

Comment: True! That takes me to something else. Wedding pictures and stuff. Some lucky guy opening a duff beer. (both with and without www) :)

Comment: @l3dx, lol yeah that's my pictures. But the duff beer doesn't help solving my issue unfortunately :)

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache yet?

Comment: try with a different browser (or smartphone or tablet or whatever) to verify it's not just browser DNS cache

Comment: @l3dx Please, write an *answer* so we can upvote it and leave the post as *answered*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eliah, I cannot edit my original answer as it's been deleted. I'll write it here again because I believe it is the answer:

It was indeed the browser dns cache. You guys were right.

I basically walked away from computer and tried again a few hours later and it just worked. I guess if I had tried with a different browser it would have work too.

Thanks for helping !